# Failed to resolve metadata in Breeze

Tags: breeze

i wrote ODataserver using webapi asp.net, when i try to resolve the metadata i get this error

> Unable to process returned metadata: A nonnullable DataProperty cannot have a null defaultValue. Name: undefined